# Cant get element generated by javaScript with Selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to bypass a website which uses cloudflare's botdetection and DDos-protection. I am using selenium. when the page load request is sent, the page starts loading and an element appears on the screen.[image: element appears on the screen]

the html looks like this:

[image: html]

the `white box` is a `span named 'mark'` and the `hidden blue box` is a `'input' tag with type 'checkbox'`.

I tried to get the elements it with usual ways like `driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "class")` also xpath, cssSelector and JsPath but didnt work. note I have waited manually to element fully appear on the screen and the problem is not about waiting for element to be loaded.

because it was generated by js so I tried `element = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('$cssSelector')")` pattern. also with xpath and JsPath. they also didnt work and elements were not found.

the code:

```
markSpanJsPath = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('#cf-stage > div.ctp-checkbox-container > label > span')")
if markSpanJsPath:#kkk
    print('found markSpanJsPath')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", markSpanJsPath)
    print('found markSpanJsPath js click')
markSpanXpath = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cf-stage"]/div[6]/label/span')
if markSpanXpath:
    print('found markSpanXpath')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", markSpanXpath)
    print('found markSpanXpath js click')
```

printed nothing.

so how to click on one of 'mark span' or 'checkbox' to pass the 'human verification'?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be `find_element()` not `find_elements()`

use below xpath to identify and click.

```
markSpanXpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//label[@class="ctp-checkbox-label"]//span[@class="mark"]')

markSpanXpath.click()
```

if above click doesn't work try java scripts.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", markSpanXpath)
```

Comment: @FarhangAmaji, Any luck? Please let me know the status?

Comment: I am loading the page serveral times and it doesnt show again, but I will check it and it gets on, btw way I think I won't work because the using `find_element` instead of `find_elements` doesnt make difference in `if markSpanXpath:` and also the alternative xpath probably wont change anything. the xpath I had used was taken from chrome inspect, so technically its correct.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji, `find_elements()` returns `list` not the `webelement`. where as `find_element()` returns webelement. `click` event won't work on list, click should be on `webelement`. Hope you understtod.#

Comment: I know. but `if markSpanXpath:` works in both ways, and u r right, if it had passed the if it would have made an error because of clicking on a list, but the problem is it didnt pass the `if`.

Comment: Do you have public url to check whats the issue?

Comment: u should use irans proxy and here the site `https://ckgsir.com/bluestrip-widget`

Comment: In that case I can't help you sorry!

Comment: it gave error: `*** selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //label[@class="ctp-checkbox-label"/span[@class="mark"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//label[@class="ctp-checkbox-label"/span[@class="mark"]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Comment: maybe its related to another problem, I mean not necessarily that ur xpath is wrong. because it gave same error for my last xpath also

Comment: @FarhangAmaji, You have used wrong `xpath` , this is the xpath `//label[@class="ctp-checkbox-label"]//span[@class="mark"]`

Comment: the last error I just wrote here 2 comments ago was for using `find_element` instead of `find_elements`. `find_element` gives error when it doesnt find, and `find_elements` returns empty list. anyway it cant find the element.

Comment: its was in a iframe :/ :))